# How to assign variables to hosts scattered over different groups?

Tags: ansible

I am using an ansible playbook, the inventory to this playbook looks something like

```
all:
  children:
    groupA:
      hosts:
        hostA1
      children:
        grpSpecial:
          hostAspecial1
    groupB:
      hosts:
        hostB1
      children:
        grpSpecial:
          hostBspecial1
```

So there is one subgroup `grpSpecial` in both main groups `groupA` and `groupB`.

For all the groups I have a group_vars file. So there is one `all.yml`, `groupA.yml`, `groupB.yml` and `grpSpecial.yml`. I defined some variables in `grpSpecial.yml` that I want to apply to all hosts that are part of this group, no matter in which groups they are otherwise.

What I thought would happen, is that for e.g. `hostAspecial1` ansible looks up in which groups it is, so in this case `all -> groupA -> grpSpecial`, then it applies all variables from the outer one (`all`) and then overriding/adding the next ones from `groupA` and finally `grpSpecial`.

But, what seems to happen, is that all variables defined for `groupA` **and** `groupB` are passed down to `grpSpecial`. So even `hostBspecial1`, which is obviously not a member of `groupA` does inherit somehow all the variables defined for `groupA` and vice versa.

So I wonder

1. Why is it like this?
2. How to assign a set of variables only to some hosts without writing them into the inventory all day long?

I am obiously not an ansible expert, so I might overlook some essential features here.

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32247 explains this limitation